# Face recognition function working fine with static path but failing with dynamic path in flask post request

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from keras.models import load_model
from utils import extract_face_roi
import pickle
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
import os
from Database import list_all_students
from flask import request
from flask import Flask,jsonify
from utils import load_image

model=load_model('facenet_keras.h5')

app = Flask(__name__)
def match_faces(emb1,emb2):
    #Matches two faces by distance.
    score=cosine(emb1,emb2)
    if score<0.45:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

#Extracts the faces from image and matches with that in database.
def get_embedding(model,face):
    face=face.astype('float32')
    mean,std=face.mean(),face.std()
    face=(face-mean)/std
    face=np.expand_dims(face,axis=0)
    embedding=model.predict(face)
    return embedding[0]


Normaliser = Normalizer(norm='l2')

def load_database_faces(em_path,filename):
    #Loads the embedding of each face.
    with open(os.path.join(em_path,str(filename)),"rb") as f:
        embeddingArr=pickle.load(f)
    return embeddingArr



def get_attendence(img):
    faceArr=extract_face_roi(img)
    allembeddings=[[Each['Name'],Each['Embedding']] for Each in list_all_students()]
    matches=[]
    for face in faceArr:
     face=get_embedding(model,face)
     face=np.reshape(face,(-1,2))
     face=Normaliser.transform(face)
     face=np.reshape(face,(128,))



     for i in range(len(allembeddings)):
         isMatched=match_faces(face,pickle.loads(allembeddings[i][1]))

         if isMatched==1:
             matches.append(allembeddings[i][0])
             break


    return matches
#Parses the path from JSON request,loads the image and calls the function to get name of people.

@app.route('/process',methods=['POST'])
def process():
    stlist=[]
    data=request.get_json()
    path=data['path']
    methReq=data['methReq']
    if methReq=="Getit":
        img=load_image(path)
        stlist=get_attendence(img)
        return jsonify({"List:":stlist})


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

I created a function which finds out the people present in a image and compares with the people present in the database.It works perfectly when I provide the path statically but fails when I pass the path using flask post request.

I am posting the request to the flask server which I created in JSON format and in the backend I am extracting the path from it and then I am trying to match people using get_attendence function.

```
Produces following error:-
face=get_embedding(model,face)
File "Main.py", line 31, in get_embedding
embedding=model.predict(face)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1164, in predict
self._make_predict_function()
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 554, in _make_predict_function**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2744, in function
return Function(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2546, in __init__
with tf.control_dependencies(self.outputs):
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5004, in control_dependencies
return get_default_graph().control_dependencies(control_inputs)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4543, in control_dependencies
c = self.as_graph_element(c)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3490, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3569, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Bottleneck_BatchNorm/cond/Merge:0", shape=(?, 128), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2019 20:07:08] "[1m[35mPOST /process HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -
```

It worked fine when I call function like this:

```
list1=get_attendence('test_images/image1.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error cause because with each request the flask creates new thread and tensor graph.
The problem can be solved by adding 'graph = tf.get_default_graph()' after loading the model as using the graph obtained with 'graph = tf.get_default_graph()' as default graph for prediction.